# Selecting part of a dataframe based on whether element is in an external array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection

I'm trying to select a subsection of a pandas dataframe where a certain condition is met -- in this case that each element of a certain column is part of an external list. I was surprised to find that this doesn't work because other conditional statements with .loc are so easy. How can I make this work?

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_dict = {'first': [0,1,0,0,1,0], 'second': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}

test_df =  pd.DataFrame(test_dict)

arr1 = [-1,-4,2,-9,8,7,-5,5,-8,0]
arr2 = [2,5]


new_df1 = test_df.loc[test_df.second in arr1]
new_df2 = test_df.loc[test_df.second in arr2]

print new_df1
print new_df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [Series.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) what you were looking for?

```
In [55]: new_df1 = test_df.loc[test_df.second.isin(arr1)]

In [56]: new_df2 = test_df.loc[test_df.second.isin(arr2)]

In [57]: new_df1
Out[57]:
   first  second
1      1       2
4      1       5

In [58]: new_df2
Out[58]:
   first  second
1      1       2
4      1       5
```

you can also use SQL like style - [DataFrame.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [60]: test_df.query("second in @arr1")
Out[60]:
   first  second
1      1       2
4      1       5
```